# Gradle build failing with compile time errors while the Android Studio IDE shows no such error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Gradle build is failing with compile time errors while the Android Studio IDE reports no such error. It usually occurs with support library classes. It looks as if gradle can't find existing classes so it throws an `error: cannot find symbol`.

```
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer>gradlew.bat assembleDebug        
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                             
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE     
:app:checkDebugManifest                
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:compileLint                
:licensesdialoglibrary:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:checkReleaseManifest                
:licensesdialoglibrary:prepareReleaseDependencies                
:licensesdialoglibrary:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE     
:licensesdialoglibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE      
:licensesdialoglibrary:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE      
:licensesdialoglibrary:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE      
:licensesdialoglibrary:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE      
:licensesdialoglibrary:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE      
:licensesdialoglibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:licensesdialoglibrary:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:compileLint                 
:quickscroll:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:preBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:checkReleaseManifest                 
:quickscroll:prepareReleaseDependencies                 
:quickscroll:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:quickscroll:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:compileLint                 
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:checkReleaseManifest                 
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:prepareReleaseDependencies                 
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE      
:velocityviewpagerlibrary:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareAsiaIvityAndroidDragSortListview10Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGithubJakeWhartonViewPagerIndicator241Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComNhaarmanListviewanimationsLibCore310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComNhaarmanListviewanimationsLibManipulation310Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComPkmmteViewCircularimageview11Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareDrakPlayerLicensesdialoglibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareDrakPlayerQuickscrollUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareDrakPlayerVelocityviewpagerlibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareDebugDependencies                 
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac                 
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Transformers\DepthPageTransformer.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class PageTransformer              
  location: class ViewPager                    
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\AudioPlaybackService.java:868: error: cannot find symbol
        Notification notification = mNotificationBuilder.build();
                                                        ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mNotificationBuilder of type Builder
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\AudioPlaybackService.java:967: error: cannot find symbol
        Notification notification = mNotificationBuilder.build();
                                                        ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mNotificationBuilder of type Builder
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncAutoGetAlbumArtTask.java:497: error: cannot find symbol
        AutoFetchAlbumArtService.builder.setProgress(dataURIsList.size(), currentProgress, false);
                                        ^      
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable builder of type Builder   
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncAutoGetAlbumArtTask.java:498: error: cannot find symbol
        AutoFetchAlbumArtService.notification = AutoFetchAlbumArtService.builder.build();
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable builder of type Builder   
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncAutoGetAlbumArtTask.java:521: error: cannot find symbol
        AutoFetchAlbumArtService.builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                                        ^      
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable builder of type Builder   
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncAutoGetAlbumArtTask.java:522: error: cannot find symbol
        AutoFetchAlbumArtService.notification = AutoFetchAlbumArtService.builder.build();
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable builder of type Builder   
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\BuildMusicLibraryService.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);      
                ^                              
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\BuildMusicLibraryService.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        mNotification = mBuilder.build();      
                                ^              
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\BuildMusicLibraryService.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
        mBuilder.setProgress(maxProgress, overallProgress, false);
                ^                              
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\BuildMusicLibraryService.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
        mNotification = mBuilder.build();      
                                ^              
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
        PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
                                      ^        
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
                PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.build());
                                              ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:339: error: cannot find symbol
                PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.setProgress(fileSize, currentDownloadedSize, false);
                                              ^
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:341: error: cannot find symbol
                PinGMusicSongsService.mNotifyManager.notify(PinGMusicSongsService.notificationID, PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.build());
                                                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:350: error: incompatible types
                    PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
                                                     ^
  required: android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
  found:    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:354: error: cannot find symbol
                    PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:355: error: cannot find symbol
                    PinGMusicSongsService.mNotifyManager.notify(PinGMusicSongsService.notificationID, PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.build());
                                                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:395: error: cannot find symbol
        PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                                      ^        
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\AsyncTasks\AsyncPinSongsTask.java:398: error: cannot find symbol
        PinGMusicSongsService.mNotifyManager.notify(PinGMusicSongsService.notificationID, PinGMusicSongsService.mBuilder.build());
                                                                                                                        ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\AutoFetchAlbumArtService.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        notification = builder.build();        
                              ^                
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable builder of type Builder   
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\PinGMusicSongsService.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);      
                ^                              
  symbol:   method setProgress(int,int,boolean)
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\Services\PinGMusicSongsService.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        mNotifyManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
                                                      ^
  symbol:   method build()                     
  location: variable mBuilder of type Builder  
C:\Users\Binoy\AndroidstudioProjects\DrakPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\jams\music\player\WelcomeActivity\MusicFoldersFragment.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
        mChildFragmentManager = this.getChildFragmentManager();
                                    ^          
  symbol: method getChildFragmentManager()     
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
24 errors                                      
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 1 mins 26.784 secs
```

I have tried the following with no success:

- Clean and build
- Try updated support library v4, v7, v8, v13
- Delete .gradle/* and build
- Check and used various versions in gradle-wrapper.properties

Here's my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vibhinna.music"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        //RenderScript backward compatibility for guassian blurs.
        renderscriptTargetApi rootProject.ext.renderscriptTargetApi
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bug in Gradle v0.7.1. The LICENSE and NOTICE files in the Apache Commons
     * library jars need to be excluded or the project won't compile/build.
     */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
        main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java'] } }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/ijabz/maven' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':licensesdialoglibrary')
    compile project(':quickscroll')
    compile project(':velocityviewpagerlibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'asia.ivity.android:drag-sort-listview:1.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'net.jthink:jaudiotagger:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev118-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:parent:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you by any chance solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle dependencies and the IDE can get out of sync.  There is a button in Android Studio that will resync dependencies.  Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set minifyEnabled to false if you don't need to obfuscate your code.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
```